# How to view blob data as image in mySQL workbench?

Tags: html, node.js, file-upload, blob, mysql-workbench

I have stored an Image file as BLOB in MySQL database and I need to view the image in the MySQL workbench. Can I do that? if I can , then how? plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the blob cell in the result grid and select "Open Value in Editor", which will show a new dialog where you can view the blob data, either as text, image or hex listing:

[image]

Comment: I have done that but it shows only as binary and text. there is no image option.

Comment: Maybe the blob data isn't really an image?

Comment: I have uploaded the link of the image as the blob.That should do it right?

Comment: A link is just text (a URL). MySQLWorkbench will not download anything.